# Old show involving three kids and a lizard thing. The sole girl in the group is some sort of space/interdimensional cop with the lizard as her partner

Tags: story-identification, tv

This show was on Netflix when I saw it. It was, I believe, half live-action show, half CGI.

It is about three people and a lizard thing. Two are kids, male; they are generic '90s/early 2000s characters. The other human main character is a girl who turns out to be some sort of space/interdimensional cop with the lizard being her partner. The kids find out and help her fight the main villain, who is controlling the principal, I think. The world they enter when doing hero things is a CGI game-like world.

I have been haunted for a while about not being able to find it. The only thing I might remember is that I believe the first letter of the show’s name was an 'E.'

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, you mentioned a principal, so was a school quite prominent in the show?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. As for what year I believe I saw this around 2010? It was very long ago but from what I remember the school was pretty prominent. Though it has been so long so some details are fuzzy. If this could help in any way one puzzle they solve had the answer of salt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[Zixx Level One](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/Zixx)*** (2004-2009)...?

> **An alien named Zixx Phunkee-Zee and her partner Flanngo crash land on Earth while investigating a lead on behalf of The Network.** Once there they discover that the planet isn't as insignificant as it seems. For one thing, it's home to an ancient pocket dimension maze known as The Keep, which just so happens to operate a lot like an Earth video game. It's also where the evil Hargokk Empire is planning its return. Led by Deeth, they seek to resurrect the evil alien warlord Oncolon from deep within The Keep and take over the universe.
>
> **Fortunately for Zixx and Flanngo, they receive help from local human children in investigating the secrets of The Keep and fighting off Deeth and his cronies. Best friends Adam and Griff help the duo in Level One,** later being swapped out for Riley, Megan, and Dwayne in Level Two and Level Three.

As mentioned in the synopsis, the protagonists are an Intergalactic Network agent (who looks like a human girl), her partner (who resembles a small dinosaur), and two school boys from Earth. The scenes set on Earth are live-action, whilst the scenes set in the Keep (a cyber dimension) are 3D-animated.

You can view the scene where the four protagonists meet around the [11:33](https://youtu.be/NtwhiFHOPQs?t=693) mark in the video below.

The school principal is featured as an antagonist. You can view a scene with him at around the [15:19](https://youtu.be/NtwhiFHOPQs?t=919) mark.

Comment: My god. Yes, yes it is. This is it. I can’t believe I would actually see it again. I was starting to think that I completely made it up, but somewhere deep inside I knew it was real.

Comment: @MadLich - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.